# Troubles using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im developing a simple app and i need to save a couple of user data so im using AsyncStorage like that:

```
const storeAge = async (age) => {
        try {
            console.log("STORED age: " +  age);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("@age", age);
        } catch (e) {
            // saving error
        }
    };
```

And im calling this function here:

```
<SetupInfo
    visible={isStartUp}
    onRegist={registHandler}
    onRegistDataSave={storeAge}
/>
```

The `onRegistDataSave` is called on a press of a button on the SetupInfo component:

```
const addRegistHandlerMemory = () => {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            props.onRegistDataSave(age / 12);
        } else {
            props.onRegistDataSave(age);
        }
        setAge("");
    };
```

...

```
<Button
    title="REGIST"
    onPress={() => {
        addRegistHandler();
        addRegistHandlerMemory();
        }}
        style={styles.button}
    />
```

The console.log on store.age is showing the correct input when button is pressed, but when i reload the app and call this:

```
const getAge = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@age");
        if (value !== null) {
            console.log("valor" + value)
            setAppMode(false);
            setAge(parseFloat(value));

        }
        console.log("age " + value);
    } catch (e) {
        // error reading value
    }

};
```

the value I got is null, why is this happening?

(Well i think i know becouse im doing the same think to save data on one array and the last value is not saved which means that probably is saving on the next render that for me - a noob on this- doent make sense since the set age is an async funtion that should avoid that...)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I figure it out where the error was. Turns out I was saving a number and AsyncStorage just saves Strings, so i just need to add `const string = toString(age);` on `storeAge` and save that value.